# Clearing EditText when onResume()

Tags: android, onresume

I am creating an app where if the user leaves the app by any means and returns, I would like all the EditText fields cleared.

I have created some code that I thought would work which is:

```
@Override
public void onResume {
    super.onResume;
    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberEntry).setText("");
    (EditText)findViewById(R.in.NameEntry).setText("");
}
```

However when I click on the Help menu (done through `onMenuItemSelected()`) and ask for help the app gets the help file and gets it ready to draw but then crashes. I can't figure out why. Any advice would be appreciated.

Or if anyone has another method that will work.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you get a crash, you should post the logcat with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with R.in, did you mean to type R.id.NameEntry?

```
@Override
public void onResume {
    super.onResume;
    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberEntry).setText("");
    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameEntry).setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the typo theisenp said, you may need to cast the views to EditText's **before** calling setText --

```
@Override
public void onResume {
    super.onResume;
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberEntry)).setText("");
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameEntry)).setText("");
}
```

Notice the extra set of parenthesis.